# Got rejected after giving Postdoc interviews for the umpteenth time. Am I doing something wrong or am I just unqualified for jobs?

Tags: postdocs, interview, rejection

I am fed up with getting rejections after rejection. I have applied to over 30 Postdoc positions and got just three interview invitations. I thought I did well in the interview consisting of 15-20 minutes presentation. However, for each of these, I never got the second interview call.

I don't know what I am doing wrong. These openings were quite a bit different than what I have done in my PhD and am doing now. But, I thought it natural to do work in slightly different topic than PhD work, so shouldn't the employers be more interested in my ability to do the job rather than whether I have done similar work before.

I don't know if I can get anything. For the past year I have been working with my PhD advisor as a postdoc due to issues in leaving the current place of residence considering covid and associated visa issues. But now as things are getting better, I want to move out to other places.

I am just not getting any positive response. I might just not be capable or might be too mediocre to get anything. I just want to roll up and cry. I have lost all motivation to study, work and write the pending papers.

Is there any way to know if I am doing something wrong or am I just unqualified for jobs?

I have applied is 20 industrial jobs as well, I got rejected from the only interview call I received.

I am just fed up.

Comment: You could try asking the three places you interview for feedback, if you haven't already. You probably won't get anything useful - everyone's afraid of saying the wrong thing and being sued - but you might get lucky and get something specific.

Comment: I’ve missed more than 9000 shots in my career. I’ve lost almost 300 games. 26 times I’ve been trusted to take the game winning shot and missed. I’ve failed over and over and over again in my life. And that is why I succeed. —Michael Jordan

Comment: You say: " shouldn't the employers be more interested in my ability to do the job rather than whether I have done similar work before", so let me ask the obvious: what are you doing to convince them that you can do the job, if you have not done it before?

Comment: @jasmine unfortunately Michael Jordan does not apply here.  You don't have the luxury of playing the long game.

Comment: Did you apply for your own fundings? The PhD to PostDoc is the second step of the academic pyramid,  someone has to succumb to it, most often on no other basis than "statistically unlucky" ... only few PhDs will get a PostDoc position, likely the ratio PD/PhD is even smaller than PhD/MSc ...

Comment: I feel the number 50 "positions applied" isn't that big a number. With so much competition around, I feel you should try to apply to a lot more opportunities.

Comment: Do you offer what they need? How do you demonstrate this?

Comment: Oh man I had the same exact situation! 3 postdoc interviews, but I didn't get any offers. So I know how frustrating it is, especially not knowing "what I am doing wrong." You probably aren't doing anything wrong, though. I mean, your interviewers decided based on your application, recommendation letters, etc., that you were a top candidate! I think with the job market, you might have to go through more than one round of postdoc applications, depending on the field. A similar thing holds for tenure-track jobs. Some people don't get offers the first time they apply, but get it next year.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs I don't know how OP is supposed to answer this question. Usually the only feedback you get from the potential supervisor is "I was very impressed. But you weren't picked. Sorry. Good luck." Keep in mind that OP made it to the interview stage, so there was probably nothing off with their application.

Comment: @Mehta  I agree, many times it's not answerable, but sometimes it is.

Comment: Though your field/location may be different and norms vary, I'd say it would not be too unusual for interviews to be done for only the top 2-3 candidates. So if you've been the top 2-3 candidates 3 times, that's still a fairly good sign, while also not particularly unusual that you didn't an offer: most candidates have to be rejected for any given job opening.

Comment: @BryanKrause But let's say that you were one of the top 3 candidates for 3 interviews, and you had an equally likely chance. The chances of being rejected from one is 2/3, so the probability of being rejected from all 3 is 8/27, which is about 30%. So OP would have a 70% chance of getting an offer, which could be better but are still decent odds.

Comment: @Mehta Things that happen 30% of the time happen quite a lot.

Answer (score 9):

Times are hard in academia. There is little you can do but keep trying, but also evaluate your application materials from top to bottom to see if there is anything there that might be misunderstood. Talk to your letter writers, for example.

I finished my degree in very bad times (mathematics). I sent several hundred applications and got two offers for temporary positions, not even postdocs. I explored actuarial work, but hated the idea. The temp position I took ended in two years, during which I sent several hundred more applications and got one offer - from an essentially invisible place. I started a good teaching career there and after several years moved, with some more painful points, to a better position.

It wasn't the career I envisioned as a student, but it turned out to be rewarding. But there were few options at the time. Some of my contemporaries at graduation were pumping gas (yes, it was that long ago).

All you can really do is keep trying and make the best compromises for yourself. You can still think. You can have an active intellectual life. You can make enough money - somehow - probably. But the times are what they are. Wishing for better isn't going to change that. Keep your mind alive.

Comment: It's hard to predict the future. A friend of mine, years ago, was starting PhD work in Mathematics. The future looked bright, the American Mathematical Society was falling over itself with optimistic predictions for the job market in the four years, the huge shortage of mathematicians, etc. This was sometime round 1988. A few years later the Cold War ended, the academic and nonacademic job markets tanked, and there was a flood of excellent ex-USSR talent into the remaining tenure track positions. All you can do is take your best shot and go with it. Set your goals but don't be deluded by them.

Comment: +1 for the two last sentences alone!

Comment: "Some of my contemporaries at graduation were pumping gas" Or they lived in Oregon or NJ